# posix regex not match a word

Tags: regex, posix

So for example I'm trying to not match 'test'. I've tried [^t][^e][^s][^t]. It won't match it, but it also won't match if at least one of the characters match the notes in the same position.

Any idea how to get around this?

Just a note, this is POSIX version of regex, there are no look-aheads or look-behinds.

Also, to clarify, the word I want is between certain characters, i.e. for the string "sdkfjdlskj <dsfdjslj@example.com>" I am looking for everything between '<>'. The email part is easy, but not matching a certain word is quite boggling.

Comment: POSIX does not support lookaheads or lookbehinds

Comment: As stated, this is POSIX version, no look aheads/behinds

Comment: Is it [**POSIX Basic Regular Expressions**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) or **POSIX Extended Regular Expressions**?

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to get past that is to put a test at each position in the word.

[Compressed](http://www.regexformat.com)

`([^t]+|(t([^e]|$)|te([^s]|$)|tes([^t]|$)))+`

[Formatted](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (                          # (1 start)
      [^t]+ 
   |  
      (                          # (2 start)
           t
           ( [^e] | $ )               # (3)
        |  te
           ( [^s] | $ )               # (4)
        |  tes
           ( [^t] | $ )               # (5)
      )                          # (2 end)
 )+                         # (1 end)
```

Comment: It seems, with your editing near the start of the pattern you accidentally added the harmful `([`.

Comment: @Armali - Indeed a typo in _Compressed_, fixed. Thanks!